# Where should my config files be located to avoid ubuntu run & auto run issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Spring boot application which reads some config files when it bootstraps itself. In the java code I use a base_path like:

```
private static final String ubuntu_base_path=
        FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

and I will try to find the config files in some location like `ubuntu_base_path+config_file_name`.

By doing this I hit two problems, letting me wondering if my `basePath` idea is a good one or not.

1. I have to always run the spring boot `jar` file with `java -jar` command under the directory where the config files is located, otherwise, the config files cannot be found, since the `java -jar` command will try to find these files under the `.` directory (current directory where the command is fired.).
2. If I try to auto run the spring boot service in ubuntu, I will fail, I am not sure but I guess that is becasue I have not `cd` to the directory where the config files are located, and hence they can not be found.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Configure the classpath in your run command ('-cp=...') to point to the folder where the config files reside. Spring should find them if they are located in the classpath.

Comment: What config files are you talking about, the standard Spring ones, or your own?

Comment: @Steve my own files.

Comment: Locating external files is often a pain.  That's why, when possible, it is usually easiest to put them in your .jar file.  Otherwise, you have to have some way to deduce where they are.  You're using "from the cwd when the program was run", but that's kinda cumbersome.  I see two other options: 1) pick a hard-coded location, or 2) pass a parameter to your program telling it where the config file(s) is/are.  I've used the latter solution most of the time when I run into this issue. So like: `java -Dconfig_file_loc=/home/joe/prog/configs -jar /path/to/jarfile`

Comment: @Steve `System.getProperty(“config_file_loc”)`  to get the path?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.